# Symfony 1.4 throwing an "Out of memory" on a really simple query

Tags: mysql, memory, symfony-1.4

I have a really simple query as shown below:

```
$result = Doctrine_Query::create()
->select('t.id, t.name, DATE(t.date_start) as date_start, ti.*')
->from('table t')
->leftJoin('t.foreigh_table ti')
->where("(DATE(t.date_start) BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate')")
->andWhere('t.user='.$userId)
->andWhere('t.is_public=1');
```

and assign the query to DoctrinePager plugin like this:

```
$this->data = new sfDoctrinePager(null, 7);
$this->data->setQuery($result);
$this->data->setPage($request->getParameter('p', 1));
$this->data->init();
```

But, an "Out of memory" is always thrown:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 842260576 bytes) in /home/.../lib/vendor/symfony/lib/debug/sfWebDebug.class.php on line 170
```

I can't believe that 1GB RAM is not enough for this simple query.

Do you guys have any idea?

**Update**
Finally found out what happens. A print_r() command in View has consumed all the memory, just comment it out & everything is good again.

Comment: Doesn't look like a simple query to me although I agree it shouldn't be running out of memory. How many results are you returning?

Comment: Only 3 are returning Rob. However, I've had found out what happens here as in updated part.

Comment: @RyanB can you post your update as an answer an accept it?

Comment: Tried before j0k, but I'm a new comer & didn't have enough reputation to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out what happens. A print_r() command in View has consumed all the memory, just comment it out & everything is good again